# How can I evaluate $\lvert -34 \rvert$? What is this operation called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $\lvert -34 \rvert$ ? How is this solved. This may probably be simple but i'm having trouble with it. I don't know how to go about solving this

Comment: Do you mean the absolute value?

Answer (score 2):

The $\lvert x \rvert$ operator is called **absolute value**, and it is really a function that behaves this way: **if $x$ is positive, leave it alone**, but **if $x$ is negative, multiply it by $-1$**. The result of an absolute value is always positive. One can generalize: $$\lvert x \rvert = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} x & \mbox{ if } x\geq 0 \\ -x & \mbox{ if } x<0\end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 2):

Thinking in terms of $x$ being on a number line, the absolute value of $x$ (your |x|) is the distance from $x$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

When two bars || surround an expression, it means that we take the **absoulute value** of that expression.

if $x$ is negative than the absolute value of $x$, will be positive.

Here is an example:

$$x = -1$$
 $$|x| = 1 $$

you should be able to solve your problem now.